# How to pull only the desired element with xml? (Nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri

Is it possible to pull only the data `code="article"` from the block?

```
<param name="Артикул" code="article">LS_745094</param>
<param name="Комментарий" code="comment"/>
<param name="Цвета" code="colors">белый, прозрачный</param>
```

I do `doc.css("offer param")`

Receive all the `param`

I only need one `<param name="Артикул" code="article">LS_745094</param>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't clear nor is it asked well. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We need the minimal example of your code that demonstrates the problem, along with the output you expect.

Answer (score 2):

For given xml

```
<node>
  <param name="Артикул" code="article">LS_745094</param>
  <param name="Комментарий" code="comment"/>
  <param name="Цвета" code="colors">белый, прозрачный</param>
</node>
```

you can try this

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('YOUR_FILE'))    
el = xml.xpath('//param[@code="article"]')
```

It would give you

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdf8880a8ac name="param" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fdf8880a7a8 name="name" value="Артикул">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fdf8880a794 name="code" value="article">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf8880788c "LS_745094">]>]
```

Then you can fetch any properties of `el`

```
el.text # => LS_745094
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking, so pick one:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<param name="Артикул" code="article">LS_745094</param>
<param name="Комментарий" code="comment"/>
<param name="Цвета" code="colors">белый, прозрачный</param>
EOT

doc.search('param').map(&:to_html)
# => ["<param name=\"&#x410;&#x440;&#x442;&#x438;&#x43A;&#x443;&#x43B;\" code=\"article\">",
#     "<param name=\"&#x41A;&#x43E;&#x43C;&#x43C;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x442;&#x430;&#x440;&#x438;&#x439;\" code=\"comment\">",
#     "<param name=\"&#x426;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;&#x430;\" code=\"colors\">"]
```

`search` returns all matching nodes as a NodeSet. That's fine if you need to iterate over them but often it's overkill.

```
doc.at('param')['code'] # => "article"
doc.at('param').text # => "LS_745094"
```

`at` is the same as `search('...').first`, returning the first matching node. So the above code finds the first `<param>` and returns it. That'd be useful if you know the tag you want is always the first one.

```
doc.at('param[code="article"]').text # => "LS_745094"
doc.at('param[name="Артикул"]')['code'] # => "article"
doc.at('param[name="Артикул"]').text # => "LS_745094"
```

If you need to supply more detail to the selector you can use parameters in the tag along with their values. Once you have the node you want you can access its parameters by treating it like a hash, or, if you want the text the node wraps use `text`.

Note, I'm using CSS selectors. Nokogiri supports CSS and XPath selectors. CSS is more readable and suffices for the majority of lookups. XPath is more powerful, often more complex and visually noisy.